# When using a container powered by itemrenderers, is there a way to make the rendering not stall?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I'm developing on Flex 4. I have a datagrid container and custom itemrenderer with a text field, a button and a few boxes. Every time some data is displayed, the app stalls for a second or two before rendering completely. Is there any way to make it render more fluidly or render one after another...?

Comment: how much data are you displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Is your renderer setting percentage-based dimensional information in a commitProperties() or updateDisplayList() override? For example, if you set a percentWidth and percentHeight, you want to do that only once, so do that in the constructor.

If you do it in another method that gets called over and over, your whole grid will be resizing and rerendering each cell until every cell has been satisfactorily sized and measured. So if your grid is 10 columns by 20 rows, that means it has to render completely at least 200 times before it's happy with its cell dimensions.